# How to split a String by last delimiter in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfml

In CF9, I have a string like `C:\Docs\472837\nyspflsys\Medical Report\XLSX_46.xlsx`

I want to split it by last backward slash, so it should look like
`array[1] = C:\Docs\472837\nyspflsys\Medical Report`  and
`array[2] = XLSX_46.xlsx`

How to do it in ColdFusion 9 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<cfset myString = "C:\Docs\472837\nyspflsys\Medical Report\XLSX_46.xlsx" />
<cfset myArray = ArrayNew(1) /> 
<cfset myArray[2] = ListLast(myString, "\") />
<cfset myArray[1] = REReplace(myString, "\\" & myArray[2] & "$", "") />


<cfdump var="#myArray#" />
```

Comment: Ya its worked perfectly a small change only, this line `<cfset myArray[1] = replace(myString, myArray[2] & "\", "") />` should be `<cfset myArray[1] = replace(myString, "\" & myArray[2], "") />` anyway thanks a lot Alex :-)

Answer (score 6):

You may want to consider using [GetDirectoryFromPath](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-e-g/getdirectoryfrompath.html) and [GetFileFromPath](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-e-g/getfilefrompath.html).

```
<cfset fullPath = "C:\Docs\472837\nyspflsys\Medical Report\XLSX_46.xlsx">

<cfset dirPath  = getDirectoryFromPath(fullPath)>    <!--- C:\Docs\472837\nyspflsys\Medical Report\ --->
<cfset dirPath  = reReplace(dirPath, "[\\/]$", "")>  <!--- C:\Docs\472837\nyspflsys\Medical Report  --->
<cfset fileName = getFileFromPath(fullPath)>         <!--- XLSX_46.xlsx                             --->
```

Answer (score 1):

I always use reverse and listRest in this situation because it makes sense conceptually to me.

```
<cfset test = "C:\Docs\472837\nyspflsys\Medical Report\XLSX_46.xlsx" />
<cfset arr = [
    reverse(listRest(reverse(test), "\")),
    listLast(test, "\")
] />
<cfdump var="#arr#" />
```

https://trycf.com/gist/71a788189d26944c0fa461f255ab6cc2

Could instead use `listDeleteAt(test, listLen(test, "\"), "\")` but that just doesn't feel as clean to me. Either work well enough though

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47229451/968244) about the built in functions, but if you still want to parse it yourself then this way is much more efficient than the other answers so far (example shown in cfscript syntax):

```
path = "C:\Docs\472837\nyspflsys\Medical Report\XLSX_46.xlsx";

file = listLast(path, "/\");               // account for unix path separator as well
dir  = left(path, len(path) - len(file));
```

If you are using Lucee, then you can take advantage of the negative length input for `left()`, like so:

```
dir = left(path, -len(file));             // Lucee only, passing negative length to left()
```

Bear in mind that this method keeps the trailing path separator in `dir`, so if you want to remove it you need to remove one more character, i.e. `- len(file) - 1`